# wso2 products and alfresco integration

Tags: alfresco, wso2

I've found this tutorial about installing Alfresco on WSO2 Appserver.

http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-install-alfresco-on-wso2.html

Does this mean I can delegate authentication to the wso2 security configuration also? I wouldn't want to have to manage security in both places separately.

If I were to deploy Alfresco in wso2 I would want to use the wso2 Identity Server for authentication. I was thinking about Alfresco running in wso2 Appserver using identity server for authentication and ESB for the Alfresco services. Is this approach suitable for other apps as well?

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSO2 Identity Server has an LDAP interface. So we can get third party software to use that interface and authenticate.

Moreover, if you host Alfresco within WSO2 Application Server, then the application is using the security framework exposed by WSO2 Cabon platform, thus the security integration becomes seamless. 
Not only that you will be able to leverage the security model of the WSO2 platform, but you will also be able to leverage monitoring, logging, and also the cloud capabilities such as multi-tenancy, billing, metering, when you host your applications using WSO2 Application Server. So you will be better off focusing on the business logic and the solution aspects, while the WSO2 platform can off-load you from the cross-cutting QoS concenrns.